# Gmail API: message snippet to ignore reply parts of the body

Tags: python, gmail-api

```
def GetMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):
  """Get a Message with given ID.
  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: The ID of the Message required.
  Returns:
    A Message.
  """
  try:
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id).execute()
    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error

credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds='UNREAD').execute()
messages = results.get('messages', [])

for msg in messages:
    id = msg['id']
    msgobj = GetMessage(service, 'me', id)

    print msgobj['snippet']
```

when you are replying back via gmail, you have your message and then the message from previous replies. The 'snippet' part of message picks up reply as well. I would like to just get the latest text in the email(not the reply part)

```
yeah that sounds good

On Sun, Feb 21, 2016 at 7:36 PM, <apple@gmail.com> wrote:
you want to play ball? ________________________________________ From:         banana@gmail.com
```

is there anything else besides snippet that gets latest email text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def GetMimeMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):
  """Get a Message and use it to create a MIME Message.
  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: The ID of the Message required.
  Returns:
    A MIME Message, consisting of data from Message.
  """
  try:
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,
                                             format='raw').execute()
    #print 'Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet']
    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
    mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
    for part in mime_msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            print part.get_payload()
    return mime_msg
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

I've decided to get Mimemessage instead. This seems to always have the reply part if there is one. This makes it easier to look for it and parse them out

Answer (score 2):

Nothing much can be done with it, unfortunately. [`snippet`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) is a short part of the message, which (based on API Explorer observations) usually is around 100+- characters. If the message was too short, it will get the reply part of the preceding message.

What I observed though, is that the message part of the snippet usually has the `On [date]` statement. I think an approach would be for you to check and split the message if a phrase like that was made (this will be a bit tricky though since the phrase itself can be partial as well).

Comment: so if email is more than 100 char, it wont get the reply message?